# Can't ssh nor ping into and out of the system but internet is working

Tags: networking, ssh, ping, ubuntu-mate, embedded-system

I'm new to Ubuntu. I just got a Odroid-C2 and I plan to use it as a Node.js server. I'm using the official Hardkernel Ubuntu Mate Image (should be version 16 or 14.x), and I need SSH Access to it. Not only locally but also through the internet.

The problem is that I'm not able to do that because I'm not able to see the device in my network. Surfing in the internet on the device works.
I'm using a WiFi dongle to access our router via the Odroid-C2 and a Mac.

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 (https://nmap.org) at 2016-07-11 17:42 EDT
Nmap done: 256 IP adresses (0 hosts up) ...
```

Is anyone able to help me to fix this issue and get it to work also for internet access?

**Edit:**

`arp -a` on the odroid only shows one IP, which is my router; whereas my Mac shows also the odroid now which is a wonder.

```
easy.box (192.168.2.1) at 84:9c:a6:a1:8e:b2 on en3 ifscope [ethernet]
easy.box (192.168.2.1) at 84:9c:a6:a1:8e:b2 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
odroid64 (192.168.2.109) at 24:5:f:80:aa:18 on en3 ifscope [ethernet]
odroid64 (192.168.2.109) at 24:5:f:80:aa:18 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
macbook-pro (192.168.2.175) at 40:6c:8f:3d:6f:b3 on en3 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
macbook-pro (192.168.2.193) at 14:10:9f:d7:b8:31 on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (192.168.2.255) at ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff on en3 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.57.101) at (incomplete) on vboxnet1 ifscope [ethernet]
all-systems.mcast.net (224.0.0.1) at 1:0:5e:0:0:1 on en3 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (224.0.0.251) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en3 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (239.255.255.250) at 1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa on en3 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (239.255.255.250) at 1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
```

I tried to ping other computers on my network and it seems like I got a response. Then I tried to SSH into the odroid which seems to work more or less. But it responds with "permission denied" & "connection refused".

**Edit2:**

`arp -a` shows only those devices that got pinged before, which is in my opinion very irritating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed ssh server and client on your Ubuntu?

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install sshd
```

Have you opened proper ports?

```
ufw allow 22/udp
```

Or maybe the problem lies on your interface having it NAT from your network.

Double check if from your Ubuntu, can you ping any devices from your network (router, computers).

Have your ping result here and let's see what we can do.

Comment: Not sure where the problem was but im now further. Now i have to somehow be able to get ssh access granted

Comment: More or less it seems like following your provided solution; fixed everything.

Comment: Note SSH is port 22, not port 21 :)

Comment: Hahahaha. My bad. I was thinking ftp while answer this . Sorry. Port 22.